# Youtube API pause when i press play in some mobile browser

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I have been working with youtubes javascript api for a webpage and everything has been working great. Today I noticed a problem which has not been present before. On some mobile browsers for instance firefox on Android the youtube players only works ones. If I press play(on the video) it start playing and if press pause it stops. But if I press play again it play a couple of frames and pause again. I think it is a new problem as I have done a lot of testing the last couple of weeks. Here is my code for creating the players.

```js
//Start Youtube API
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var youtubeReady = false;

//Variable for the dynamically created youtube players
var players= new Array();
var isPlaying = false;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
     youtubeReady = true;
    //The id of the iframe and is the same as the videoId 
    jQuery(".video").each(function(i, obj) {
      players[obj.id] = new YT.Player(obj.id, {         
            videoId: obj.id,
          playerVars: {
              controls: 0,
              showinfo: 0 ,
              modestbranding: 1,
              wmode: "transparent",
              html5: 1
           },   
           events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
           }
        });
     });
  }
```

Comment: It seem like it has something to do with the browser and when you press on the video. In firefox you can touch and hold on the video and a small menu appear which where you can press play or show controls. It just seems weird that it works ones.

Comment: I digged a little deeper and found that on samsung s3 stock browser you cannot pause the video by pressing the video image, it just rewind a bit and keeps playing. On firefox on my phone and tablet it keeps pausing when i am only interacting with the video image if use the controls everything works. If I copy the iframe code generated by the API and do a normal embed it works fine. I do not know if it is something to with the API or with the browsers....

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found the cause of the problems. I experinced problem in Firefox for Android and the standard browser on Samsung Galaxy S3. My setting was that youtube player had control=0 so all play and pause interaction is done by pressing the iframe/video image

In firefox the problem was that if I played the video, paused and played it again it would play for a couple of frames an pause for no reason. The cause of the problem was this line:

tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

If i change http to https it works. The same problem occur when using regular embeds if you do not link to the video with https.

However this means that the user has to activate the plugin before the video is visible and it furthermore seems to be another more laggy player that appears... When reading in forums it seems that a lot of people have problem with youtube embeds with firefox for android.

For the samsung s3 browser the problem was kind of the opposite. When playing a video and pausing it would rewind a couple frames and play again for no reason. I found that the problem was with the "control=0" parameter. If I change this to "control=2" it works, so if I want to support this browser I need to rethink my design. It do not seems to work...